# Git hangs indefinitely - broke with osx credential helper I think

Tags: macos, git, keychain

I got tired of typing my password for my bitbucket repo so I looked up a way to use ssh keys but happened upon the osx credential keychain. I thought I had installed it all correctly by following along with what was instructed in the git-scm book but something bad happened...I can't use git at all!! I then went and rm'd the credential-osxkeychain but that didn't fix my issue, neither did uninstalling and reinstalling git.

If I go into a repo that I had previously pulled down, change a file and run `git status` it hangs indefinitely.

If I make a new directory, cd into it and run `git init` that will hang indefinitely as well.

When I run `git` without any arguments the following is printed out: `Usage: git credential-osxkeychain <get|store|erase>`. I already looked at my `/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Acces.app` but I couldn't find anything to change. At this point I just want `git` back...I'm fine with typing my password.

For reference I am using OSX 10.7.2

edited to add: `which git` returns `/usr/bin/git`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `"git" status` (*with* the quotes). If that works, you've aliased `git` to something else (probably `alias git="git credential-osxkeychain"`), and you should look in `~.profile` to see if you can remove the alias.

(See the attached commentary for the debugging steps and eventual resolution).

Comment: I thought it was \ that made it go around aliases. I tried both regardless, neither worked. I also looked in `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc` and `.gitconfig`

Comment: \ works too; I'm just used to `"..."`. Did you perchance replace `git` with some sort of wrapper? What does `which git` produce?

Comment: just edited my post to say `which git` returns `/usr/bin/git`

Comment: `less /usr/bin/git` produces binary gibberish? Maybe use `Instruments.app` or `dtrace` to figure out what this apparently-modified `git` is doing?

Comment: yeah, binary gibberish indeed. actually...some of it is legible for whatever reason. and it says something like `/usr/local/share/git-core/contrib/credential/osxkeychain` or `/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.10/share/git-core/contrib/credential/osxkeychain/git-credential-osxkeychain`

Comment: It looks like you installed the `git-credential-osxkeychain` wrapper in the wrong place (did you `cp` to `/usr/bin/git` instead of `/usr/local/git/bin`?) To fix, you'll want to just delete `/usr/bin/git`; assuming `git` is still installed in `/usr/local/bin` it should take over.

Comment: Your issue would make sense given that the credential helper likely calls back to `git`, which would result in an infinite `exec` loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now. I was going to try that but I guess I didn't really have the balls to do so without an internet recommendation. It's actually installed to `/usr/local/git/bin` so I just added that to my PATH.

Comment: This worked for me and I reinstalled from brew so it had the osxkeychain already. Maybe you should add the commentary resolution to the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Hehe, I had this problem and it turned out that I  copied osxkeychain to `/usr/local/git/bin/git` rather than `/usr/local/git/bin/`.  D'oh!

Answer (score 5):

To fix this I reinstalled git from `http://git-scm.com/download/mac`
and then added `/usr/local/git/bin` to the top of the file `/etc/paths`

Comment: Never thought of that.  Nice work. Worked.  `mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git_old`   `ln -s /usr/local/git/bin/git /usr/bin/git`

Answer (score 0):

As nneonneo said above, the reason is that files - git-credential-osxkeychain and git - are installed on wrong path (path, which is not default in `/etc/paths`, which is not on the first line in `/etc/paths`). Answers above didn't work for me. What exactly I tried : 1) change order of lines in file `/etc/paths`, but file `/etc/paths` is not available for changing on Mavericks 2) delete /usr/bin/git - this also didn't help me 3) `mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git_old ln -s /usr/local/git/bin/git /usr/bin/git` also didn't. 
So I decided to describe my way. I manually take files - git-credential-osxkeychain and git from `/usr/local/git/bin` and put in `/usr/bin/git` (cause `/usr/bin/git` - is the first path in `/etc/paths`). To get the path like `/etc/paths` in finder, just push Command+Shift+G and put path.