# Why is git hanging - have to press enter twice after commands?

Tags: git, github, terminal

**Edit: Summary: Every command entered in Git produces a hanging cursor which then says "bad input" if anything is typed before enter is pressed. No commands produce any results. I tried a fresh install with no results.**

I am *completely* new to Git. No idea what I'm doing whatsoever. (I'm on a Mac)

I was following the basic instructions on the site:

```
touch README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:aerovistae/MetPetDB-Mobile.git
git push -u origin master
```

But as soon as I type in "git init", the terminal hangs. I press enter, nothing happens, the prompt doesn't start a new line...it just starts a blank line with no blinking cursor. I press enter a second time, the prompt returns, having skipped a line in the terminal, and now waiting for my next command.

I don't really understand what's going on here, and I'm not sure if something's wrong or not.

EDIT:

Git was installed from the main downloads page.

http://git-scm.com/downloads

After I hit enter on `git init` I get the blinking cursor on a blank new line, and after a moment I hesitantly typed in `Testing` and hit enter again. It then spat out, on the next line, `bad input: Testing` and showed me a new prompt.

I tried reinstalling, but to no avail. I try other git commands, like `git config --global user.name "Meeeee"` But it doesn't matter. They all produce the same hanging.

Comment: That sounds horribly wrong. You should check your git installation.

Comment: Ideally, you should see a line like `Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/vlazarenko/a/.git/`. Do you see a `.git` directory if you type `ls -a`?

Comment: Have you tried running git init in another directory?

Comment: Not sure what other source control you're familiar with, but this should basically be the same as `hg init` or `svnadmin create`. Something is very wrong if it hangs. Just one other thought, have you checked your disk space.

Comment: @favoretti No luck. Nothing there. Perhaps my Git installation is....flawed.

Comment: Try it with a different terminal. I suppose it *could* be caused with some really bizarre/incorrect termios ..

Comment: @pst Regarding title change, I was unspecific deliberately because all subsequent commands hang as well. And I'm just using the standard Mac terminal. What other terminal is there? (I am not a very experienced developer.)

Comment: Start a terminal as root user. Perhaps its not working and you have not enough rights to execute all commands.

Comment: How did you install git? Just curious, cause maybe the problem is somewhere there :)

Comment: @Aerovistae `xterm` is also available in OS X.

Comment: Ok, that makes no sense since as far as I know git init doesn't take input.

Comment: Yeah...I don't think it has anything to do with Git. I mean, I get the same result from every git command...a hanging cursor that then says bad input if I type anything before pressing enter. This is something else...but I haven't the slightest idea what.

Comment: What does `file $(which git)` say?

Comment: For that matter, just try `which git` and make sure it's the file you just installed (in addition to the `file $(which git)` suggestion).

Comment: Looking through the git source code, there are exactly two occurrences of `"bad input:"`, both in functions called `read_credential`. It's printed in an error message only if the line read from stdin does *not* contain an `=` character. But that should only happen if you run `git credential-wincred` or `git credential-osxkeychain`. What OS are you on? ... Never mind, I see you're on MacOS -- so *something* is probably invoking `git credential-osxkeychain`. Maybe somebody else can run with this and figure out the problem.

Comment: @KeithThompson really clever detective work, I would not have thought of that.

Comment: @Aerovistae: But there are no references to `credential-osxkeychain` outside `git-credential-osxkeychain.c` and the `Makefile`, so nothing should be invoking it implicitly. Can you confirm the *exact* error message (copy-and-paste)?

Comment: *Testing* being what I type in when it hangs on any git command, before pressing enter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Considering you are on OS X, and after [Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700047/why-is-git-hanging-have-to-press-enter-twice-after-commands#comment17146902_12700047), it is possible

- you have an alias in place for git, invoking `credential-osxkeychain`.
  See "[Git hangs indefinitely - broke with osx credential helper I think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613315/git-hangs-indefinitely-broke-with-osx-credential-helper-i-think)":

> you've aliased git to something else (probably `alias git="git credential-osxkeychain"`), and you should look in `~.profile` to see if you can remove the alias.

- or  you have several git installed:

> It looks like you installed the `git-credential-osxkeychain` wrapper in the wrong place (did you `cp` to `/usr/bin/git` instead of `/usr/local/git/bin`?)
>   To fix, you'll want to just delete `/usr/bin/git`; assuming git is still installed in `/usr/local/bin` it should take over.
>
> It's actually installed to `/usr/local/git/bin` so I just added that to my `PATH`.

Comment: So weird coming back and looking at this four years later, now that I'm a proficient git user. Git is bad enough when you're brand new to the command line and the idea of version control; this bug is really awful as a first experience. Makes you feel *really* lost, like you haven't even opened the program and you've already broken something.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm perhaps you are in a directory which is not writable?

Normally you can create a directory.

```
mkdir test
cd test
git init
```

then you init an empty GIT repo in the test folder and you should see a folder named **".git"** which is hidden. Perhaps you can try to build a bare repository.

```
git --bare init
```

But your problem sounds a bit strange. Du you run your command with all rights?

Comment: I just made a folder on the desktop while I was messing around and testing, but it doesn't matter where I put it. I think the installation is broken. Somehow.

Comment: hmm perhaps you should open an terminal as Admin and test on your console.

Comment: Attempting to sudo...still hangs with no results.

Comment: sudo shouldn't matter. at all. if you can create a file there, git will succeed as well.

Comment: Perhaps you should try to reinstall your git-core package from port or try or try the new package here: http://git-scm.com/downloads