# Git hanging after installing osx credential helper

Tags: macos, git, keychain

I'm having the same problem as this thread: [Git hangs indefinitely - broke with osx credential helper I think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613315/git-hangs-indefinitely-broke-with-osx-credential-helper-i-think)

Basically -- had been running `git` without problems, then installed the `credential-osxkeychain` and `git` began hanging indefinitely after any command.  e.g., running `git init` results in a hanging prompt and any input creates an error: `bad input`

I tried following the advice to delete git from `usr/bin/git` but now it doesn't recognize anything. I tried reinstalling `git` but now it doesn't seem to recognize it.

I ran `which git` and it returns: `/usr/local/git/bin/git`

I'm somewhat new at this and don't have the balls to just start running `sudo` commands and moving things around in the `/usr/bin` directory.

Any ideas what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700047/why-is-git-hanging-have-to-press-enter-twice-after-commands/12703781#12703781 be of any help?

Comment: Thanks. I am guessing it is probably a problem with the PATH? I'm fairly new at working in the command line and have never edited a PATH explicitly, so was confused why it would do that.

Comment: I understand (and don't know MacOsX enough to be of much help), but at least that will give you some clues to follow and check out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not totally sure what I actually did to fix this problem, but resetting the terminal ended up getting it to work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and fixed it thusly:

1. uninstall git via the *uninstall.sh* that comes with the install
2. reinstall git via the installer
3. run *which git* and *cd* to the folder containing git (eg. *cd /usr/local/git/bin/*)
4. run *curl -O http://github-media-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/osx/git-credential-osxkeychain*
5. run *chmod u+x git-credential-osxkeychain*
6. run *git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain*

Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I didnt have git 1.7.10 or later installed.  Messed everything up.

To fix, I had to delete git and install a newer version.

I used homebrew to install, after deleting.

is working again.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I reinstalled git from `http://git-scm.com/download/mac`
and then added `/usr/local/git/bin` to the top of the file `/etc/paths`