# No prompt in terminal after git changes

Tags: macos, terminal

I've been trying to resolve a problem where I'm unable to clone --recursive from github. I went through the [**instructions**](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git). I finished all of the commands, and after running the command:

```
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

, the terminal is just hung up.

When I attempt to quit it, it tells me git is still running. Ctrl-C reveals `[Process completed]` but still no command prompt.

I've tried to delete the `com.apple.Terminal.plist` file, but that just deletes my preferences. I've tried rebooting as well.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.8.2

Comment: ok - I had the following in my .profile file:git config --global credential.helper cache. I commented that out and now i have a command prompt. running any git command now hangs the terminal, however.

Comment: ok - this fixed me up... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613315/git-hangs-indefinitely-broke-with-osx-credential-helper-i-think